# Match part A, but not part b in full file regex

Tags: java, regex

I have to create a single regex to search a full file to find a match to the first part of a Java XML parser, but not the second part. This will be used to protect against some XXE attacks. Unfortunately it *does* have to be a single regular expression and it *does* need to search the entire file (rather than line by line).

I'm searching through java files to find DocumentBuilderFactory and I'm looking for cases where the variable initialized is then *not* run through the setFeature below or setEntity OR find SAXParserFactory where the variable is then *not* run through the setFeature below.

Here are my cases for when I want the regex to fail:

Case A (Simple case):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
...
docBuilderFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
```

Case B (multi-line):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
.newInstance();
...
docBuilderFactory
.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
```

Case C (Using SAXParser instead of DocumentBuilder):

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
...
spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
```

To reiterate, I want the regex to find cases where either the DocumentBuilderFactory or SAXParserFactory are not followed by a setFeature or setExpandEntity.

This is what I have so far (formatted for slightly better understanding hopefully):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory (\w+).*=.*DocumentBuilderFactory
[\n|\r]?.*?
\.
[\n|\r]?.*?
newInstance\(\)
(?>.|\n|\r)*
(\1[\n|\r]?.*?\.[\n|\r]?.*?setExpandEntityReferences\(false\)
|\1[\n|\r]?.*?\.[\n|\r]?.*?setFeature\("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false\)
|\1[\n|\r]?.*?\.[\n|\r]?.*?setFeature\("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", false\)).*

|SAXParserFactory (\w+).*=.*SAXParserFactory
[\n|\r]?.*?
\.
[\n|\r]?.*?
newInstance\(\)
(?>.|\n|\r)*
(\1[\n|\r]?.*?\.[\n|\r]?.*?setFeature\("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false\)
|\1[\n|\r]?.*?\.[\n|\r]?.*?setFeature\("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", false\)).*
```

I'm having difficulty making those setFeatures so that they are not found and I'm pretty sure the setFeatures aren't being looked at at all.

Comment: Are you parsing the .java source code files? Although I am not sure how something like this should be done in the best way, that does not sound like the best idea to me. The hacker will find some way to circumvent that check. Just an idea from the top of my head: Would you be able to catch e.g. `DocumentBuilderF\u0061ctory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();`? `\u0061` is an escape sequence which translates to `a`, so the initialization above is valid.

Comment: I'm looking at source files of the product itself, the injection is on the XML, not on the java source. This is a pseudo static analysis hardening phase. The point you make above is good, but not part of this problem (luckily!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tough problem when you add the restriction that you have to do it in a single global  regex, but I was able to get the following to work, as long as you set . to match newline characters:

```
(?:DocumentBuilderFactory|SAXParserFactory)[\s\r\n]+?(\w+)[\s\r\n]*?=[\s\r\n]*?(?:DocumentBuilderFactory|SAXParserFactory)[\.\r\n]+newInstance(?!.*\1(?=[\.\r\n]+(:?setFeature|setExpandEntity)))
```

The only way I can find to do it is to put a positive lookahead inside a negative lookahead, which may not be supported by some engines, and runs quite slowly.

Comment: whoa very cool. I will try this out shortly. Do you know how to attach the SAXParser bit as well?

Comment: and don't worry about speed. this will be run on thousands of java files not very frequently, so slowness is expected

Comment: Updated the answer to include the SAXParserFactory as well.

Comment: oh! I see how the (:? part works now I think. I'll be rearranging, since your method has the SAX or Doc Factory with the setFeature part, though setFeature can be used in a few other contexts and also they should be mutually exclusive. Either way, this works great. Thanks